# Device Orinetation change notification posts when app goes to background in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, swift5, realitykit

I am facing a problem that when I press the home button (goes to background) `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)` is getting called. The code for adding an observer is `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleDeviceRotation), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)`. When I change to landscape and press the home button without changing to portrait ie from the landscape, the selector function gets called. I can not remove the observer because it is defined in a class which is calling once and is an AR application. So how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: The rotation is caused by iOS rotating the app to the other orientation and back again when the app is backgrounded. It does this so it can take snapshot images for the task switcher. If I remember correctly, it also changes dark/light mode to capture those images too.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth so how to resolve this?

Comment: I don’t think you can stop iOS doing this unless you make your app only support one orientation. In one of my apps I have checked `UIApplication.shared.applicationState` to skip code in the notification handler if I am in the background. But most apps should handle rotations. What is actually going wrong when this happens?

Comment: @GeoffHackworth the app crashes when I go to the background because of that notification post. Some AR-related codes are there in that selector method. That causes the issue

Comment: Does your app support portrait and landscape? If so, I assume it does get the notification but does not crash when rotating when it is open. Seems like the code in the handler is broken and you will need to provide more information on what the code does and what the crash looks like in Xcode.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth I have solved this using UiApplicatio.shared state. Thank you so much